# Batch replace audio using ffmpeg

Tags: macos, ffmpeg

I have a folder with mkv and aac files on my Mac. I have used ffmpeg to replace audio in mkv files with success but I can't figure out how to loop it in a folder. Let's say I have a folder with vid1.mkv, vid1.aac, vid2.mkv, vid2.aac etc. I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
for i in *.mkv; do ffmpeg -i "$i" -i "${i%.*}.aac" -c copy -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 "${i%.*}.remux.mp4" done
```

Comment: You're missing a semicolon before the `done`.

Comment: Trying to use the same (adapted) script for .mp4 and .mp3 files. The script runs fine but the output files have no audio. Any ideas?